# Auto Loading training phrases through API is usesless

Tags: api, sdk, annotations, dialogflow-es

Got confirmation from support team that although I can load training phrases into intents through API (I have 20,000 training phrases and 100 intents), I can't really use them.

Because I need anyway to annotate parameters and entities manually, and even when the training phrases are there and I can see them, they are not really trained.

So, why bother allowing to load all my phrases through API if I have to type them manually anyway? Very frustrating...

Comment: Can you clarify what the confirmation was that you "can't really use them"?

Comment: Could you please referrer the API which you actually mean? I did some research for the import/export zip files. In the "usersays" files you can define which words should be tagged with which entity. Did you expect an auto detection?

Comment: @rekire there should be a feature of auto detection just like when we add a new phrase in console. manually tagging while preparing the training data is very frustrating.

Comment: Out of my experience for Dialogflow you really don't need so much utterances. I would say just 1/5 of them you need to define for Alexa. On the other hand you are right, that would be nice, however that should not be too hard to impment that by your own. Just a couple of hours...

Comment: "When using Dialogflows SDK or API, Training phrase's annotation should be set manually.
From this link you can see an example on how to use TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addParts(),
this allows you to add parts of a single training phrase.
Using this, you can set a text or string to be annotated and matched to an entity.
Inside the addParts(), you can set the text, alias and Entity type using Part.Builder.
Your code should look something like this:
TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addParts(
  Part.newBuilder().setText(trainingPhrase).setAlias(alias).setEntityType(enti).build()).build());
)

Comment: rekire, My bot is a Q&A bot, so I need a lot of training phrases because I have thousands of questions And will have dozens of thousands in the future.